# Why is Rails not giving a 3XX on redirect and causing my unit tests to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, redirect

I'm trying out some unit tests for the first time in Ruby on Rails 5.0.1 (designed sites a few times without tests but just starting to understand the value of proper testing...) and writing a sample app to get the hang of things. I have written some tests to make sure the routing works correctly.

**test/controllers/static_page_controllers_test**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "root should get static_pages home" do
    get '/'
    assert_redirected_to static_pages_home_url
  end

  test "static_pages root should get static_pages home" do
    get '/static_pages'
    assert_redirected_to static_pages_home_url
  end

  [some other tests]

end
```

I have written some routing code to redirect from root and `static_pages` root to the `static_pages` `home` embedded ruby html file. This code does correctly redirect in the sense that when you point the browser at `/static_pages` or `/` the `static_pages/home.html.erb` page loads.

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/static_pages' => 'static_pages#home'
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/help'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  root 'static_pages#home'
end
```

When I run my unit tests for redirects they are still failing.

**`rails test`**

```
# Running:

F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_root_should_get_static_pages_home [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:6]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>


bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:4

..F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_static_pages_root_should_get_static_pages_home [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:11]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>


bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:9

.

Finished in 0.821392s, 6.0872 runs/s, 6.0872 assertions/s.

5 runs, 5 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

A quick `wget` to the root URL confirms the Rails Puma server is returning HTTP 200 instead of a 300. Do I need to manually alter the HTTP requests themselves or am I handling the redirect wrongly in some manner? How best to change this so my unit tests work correctly and the server returns the right HTTP status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that these are not actual HTTP redirects. When you set up your `root` within `routes.rb`, and then visit `"/"`, you are not going to some page first and then being told via some code that you should be redirected to a different page - you're just being taken *straight* to the root/home page.

Same goes for when you set up `"/static_pages"` to **map** (not redirect) to `"static_pages#home"`. What is happening is that the Rails server knows that when someone goes to `"/static_pages"`, the `StaticPagesController` is going to respond, specifically, the `#home` method. There is no redirect happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not redirected as in the HTTP protocol slang. You're just using properly defined routes and get a 200 OK.

[See Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

Comment: Amending to `get '/static_pages', to: redirect('static_pages/home')` causes second test to pass as per documentation. However, there seems no way to use `root` with `to: redirect` listed in the linked to doc. I can just use `get /` instead of `root`, I suppose. Is this likely to cause any side-effects, apart from being slightly less readable?

Comment: @RailsKiddie I think that your tests are misleading you. I just linked the guide to show you that you have to use a special syntax to perform a redirect, but I don't think you really want/need it.

[You may try another assertions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_routing)

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the tests and this is a really useful comment.